# ¿Como puedo ejecutar un procedure con node-firebird?

Tags: typescript, firebird

Tengo esta funcion para ejecutar las querys:

```
async function execute(
  method: 'query' | 'execute',
  command: string,
  params: any[],
  base?: string
): Promise<any[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = { ...dbOptions, database: base || dbOptions.database };

    firebird.attach(options, (err, db) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error attaching to database:', err);
        return reject(err);
      }

      db[method](command, params, (err, result) => {
        db.detach();
        if (err) {
          console.error(`Error executing ${method}:`, err);
          return reject(err);
        }

        if (result) {
          resolve(transformResult(result));
        }
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

pero al intentar ejecutar un procedure "AA_INSCRIPCIONES_GENERAR(1,1)"  me devuelve este error: "Error: Cursor is not open", me fije y en la base funciona bien el procedure, pero no logro hacer que funcione en mi codigo